# What does it mean for a function to be "conjugate to" another function?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

For instance, Lemma 7.8 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9201272.pdf

If a transformation $g_0 \in \mathcal{G}$ has the form $g_0 (w) = w + 1 + o
(1)$ as $| w | \rightarrow \infty$, then $g_0$ is conjugate within
$\mathcal{G}$ to the translation $w \rightarrow w + 1$.

Comment: dynamically conjugate (also topologically conjugate ...) are all different, here we have dynamically conjugate, it means take a mobius transform $m$, then $f$, $g$ are conjugate if $f = mgm^{-1}$.

Comment: This is because m\"obius transformations are the only automorphisms of $\mathbb{S}^2 = \mathbb{C}\cup \{\infty\}$

Comment: Try reading Silverman - Arithmetic of Dynamical systems, Beardon - Iterations of rational functions